# Lexicographically sort deeply nested lists of mixed data types in Python 3

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, comparison

In Python 3, the `list.sort()` method will do a lexicographical sort. But in Python 3, comparing a list to a `float` or `int` throws a `TypeError`, unlike in Python 2, where you can do this:

```
>>> [0, 1] < 2
False
```

**What is the best way to achieve the old Python 2 behavior?**

I've tried subclassing `list`, but for that to work, each of the nested lists must be cast to the subclass type so that all the nested comparisons use the overridden comparison methods. Is there a way of accomplishing this that doesn't resort to recursively converting each nested lists to the subclass?

I'd like to be able to compare two lists like so:

```
>>> a = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [0, 1]]
>>> b = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> a < b
False
```

The result should be `False` because `a[0][0]` is a `list` and `b[0][0]` is an `int`, and in my case `int`s should always be considered less than a `list`.

#### Edit:

I'm looking to implement a sort function that is identical to the built-in Python 3 `list.sort`, except when a `list` is being compared to a `float` or `int`, in which case the `list` should always be considered larger.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that python2 comparisons where pretty much meaningless? All `list`s are greater than all `int`s because `l` comes after `i`... do you really need this kind of sorting?

Comment: As has already been stated, comparisons of that sort are meaningless. What exactly are you trying to compare (sum of all elements, number of elements, depth of nesting)? In other words, what property of the first list makes it greater than the second list, for your purposes?

Comment: @SiHa, clarified things a bit in my edit.

Comment: Hmm. As Dan says, the tricky bit is writing a key function that returns the same type regardless of whether it's called with an `int`, `float`, or `list`, and also will correctly evaluate `list` as > `int` *and also* still work for 'normal' comparisons (9 > 3, b > a)

Answer (score 1):

Since, [as mentioned in the Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Most other objects of built-in types compare unequal unless they are
>   the same object; the choice whether one object is considered smaller
>   or larger than another one is made arbitrarily but consistently within
>   one execution of a program.

object comparison is only meaningful when two objects are of the same type. Relying on the value returned by expressions such as `[0, 1] < 2` should not be done in a program and that's why this behaviour was removed from Python 3.

To explain it further, if you have the list `[[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [0, 1]]`, this has two elements:
`[[0, 1], [2, 3]] and [0, 1]`. In order for python to sort them, it compares their internal values lexicographically, since both are lists with values `[0, 1] and [2, 3]` for the first one and `0 and 1` for the second. But, then, it has to compare `[0, 1] with 0`, which are not of the same type and, thus, the comparison produces arbitrary results.

**So, this sorting is broken.**

Having said the above, if you have some lists that can be sorted meaningfully and some that cannot (because of the above explanation), a simple solution is to catch the possible exception and then return False.

```
try:
    [0, 1] < 2
except TypeError:
    # return or assign False. True is not actually meaningful.
```

or, for list.sort()

```
try:
    x.sort()
except TypeError:
    pass    # Do nothing. Python would produce meaningless results, anyway.
```

If you want to produce a meaningful sorting (if this actually makes sense), then you will have to define a key function, as is already mentioned. This may be rather complex, though. Maybe looking at your problem from a different perspective will be better.

Comment: My problem has arisen in the course of rendering lists into a particular kind of "normal form"; for this purpose it is enough to consider a single `int` or `float` as always less than a list, no matter what its contents. Objects of different types **can** be compared meaningfully, *as long as the comparison is well-defined*, which the relation I just described definitely is.

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking about a solution. Is there any more structure to this form that could help us? Is there a limit to the depth? Also, do you create the form yourself? I'm thinking about any possibility of a hack during its creation that will help us later.

Comment: There is no hard limit to the depth, though in practice it probably won't exceed 10-15; I do create the form myself. I suppose I could keep track of the depth and use that... though if that could be avoided it would be better.

Comment: I thought of a quick and dirty hack, but it will only work if you produce your lists with the `list` builtin (no list comprehensions). You will create your subclass of list, overriding the comparison method as you mentioned, and then you will temporarily assign the subclass to the `list` name. That way, you can create your enhanced list quickly and easily and then restore the list builtin for further use. How does that sound?

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I've done for the time being. Seems to be the best option, though it feels so wrong...

Comment: Any progress? This thing is still bothering me.

Comment: Haven't found a better solution so far. I may revisit the problem when optimizing the finished product, but I'm not sure there's a clever way of avoiding any kind of ugliness.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is not to subclass `list`, but simply to [use the `key` parameter of the `sort` method to define a custom key function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions):

```
sorted(l, key=custom_key_function)
```

`custom_key_function(list_element)` should generate a standardized key for that list-element, with all keys being of the same class.

Without knowing exactly what kinds of elements your lists may contain, I won't speculate on further details of how to implement it, but I think it's fair to say from your examples that you may need to recursively sort the sub-lists using the same `custom_key_function`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slow way.

To add order between non-comparable types `A` and `B`, put their instances in tuples:

```
a = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [0, 1]]
b = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]

def deep_annotate(item):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return (1, [deep_annotate(i) for i in item])
    else:
        return (0, item)

deep_annotate(a) < deep_annotate(b)
#>>> False

deep_annotate(a) > deep_annotate(b)
#>>> True
```

Unfortunately a lot of this doesn't shortcut, which can be done by clever use of `cmp_to_key`.